# How do I remove A-Z from _POST

Tags: php

I have one form which will not return any error to user.

If user submit

```
$input = '~%$!@_)(*)*(!#_)(*&AB**23**CDEFGHIJKLMNdsf**234**OPQRSTUV**499**WXYZ'
```

I want script will remove all chars accept `0-1`

```
$replace = '23234499';
```

Then convert automate to `number_format` or `money_format`

```
$output = '23,234,499.00';
```

Let me know

---

If `no number` found on input I want the output to be `0.00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$input = '~%$!@_)(*)*(!#_)(*&AB**23**CDEFGHIJKLMNdsf**234**OPQRSTUV**499**WXYZ';
$input = preg_replace('/\D/','',$input);
$input = number_format($input,2);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/XoEcL)

Since the definition of `\D` might contain digits other than `0-9` depending on the locale. It is safer to use

```
$input = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$input);
```

Comment: How about if no number found in the input? `number_format` will not return any error?

Comment: Ok got it. `if(empty($input))`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
$str = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $your_string);
```

Comment: Or just `\D`, for clarity. :)